No data is output from Strapi
I upload the site to Vercel and add the connection data:
NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_TOKEN
and
NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL
If I run it locally via npm run dev, all the data is displayed, but as soon as I enter the same data as when I run it locally in env Vercel, everything stops being displayed
What could be the reason?
It turns out that when the site is turned on locally, all data is displayed, but when the site is deployed, it is not
